# What is resetting my softtabstop?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I have the following line in my vimrc:

```
autocmd Filetype html setlocal tabstop=8 softtabstop=8 shiftwidth=8 expandtab
```

Doesn't count for anything when I open an html file:

```
:set expandtab? sts?
noexpandtab
softtabstop=0
```

How can I go about figuring out what is resetting `expandtab` and `softtabstop`? In general, what *can* I do to find out what is making a certain change, between vimrc, my own installed plugins, plugins in the distribution, &c

I tried searching the files from `:scriptnames` for references to `softtabstop`. Some reference it or set it to 8, but none of these seem to be setting it to zero (or any other variable value).

If somebody is inclined, I'd welcome a glance at my vimrc and `:scriptnames` output in case the problem is obvious from these. You can find them [here](https://gist.github.com/jpassaro/1da25ec59b3d9c4342c6fb58aa7e5e4a).

Comment: See [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) for general help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `:verbose set <name>`, e.g.:

```
:verbose set tabstop
tabstop=4
      Last set from ~/.vim/settings.vim
```

`:verbose` also works with other commands (e.g. `:map`). See [`:help :verbose`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3averbose).

Comment: This wound up giving me nothing! Reason (see my answer) is that nothing actually set it in the first place -- my filetype was wrong and my autocmd wasn't executing. Apparently you get no "last set" message either if you set the variable yourself or if it is at a system default.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure it out:

```
:set filetype? " expecting html here
jinja
```

Makes sense because I do have a jinja plugin at work. Same autocmd for "jinja" filetype instead of html and I'm good to go.

Compiling a few things I learned along the way in case somebody else finds this answer:

- `:set filetype?` as seen above tells you what filetype vim thinks you are in
- `:verbose set <var>` tells you where the variable was last set. If it does not, you either set it yourself, or it's at system default (as was the case with me). Thank you @Carpetsmoker!
- [This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) is a good resource. Thank you (again) @Carpetsmoker for making the resource, and @Tumbler41 for pointing me to it!
- [Another good resource at vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Debug_unexpected_option_settings).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I use vim installed by brew on a mac os 10.12.6. I'm currently coding in ruby.
In my case, a recent update to vim 8.1-153 caused a change in softtabstop and expandtabs.  Using the method above by Martin Tournoij I determined that this file controlled the settings:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/8.1-153/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/ruby.vim
```

My attempts to override the settings in my ~/.gvimrc did not work.  I ended up modifying the installation's ruby.vim file (as above) which **I did not want to do**.  Here is the code with changes:

```
if get(g:, 'ruby_recommended_style', 1)
  setlocal shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 noexpandtab
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | setl sw< sts< et<'
endif
```

Comment: I don't think that really answers OP question. Anyway the right way to override a setting in an ftplugin is described at [`:h ftplugin-overrule`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule). You want to create `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim` and change the settings in this file.